# MFPF on IBM Bluemix container - Wlapp Upload Fails After 60 seconds

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, mobilefirst-server

I followed the steps in order to create and deploy a docker image of MFPF71 over Bluemix container, as [here](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/10/02/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-containers-app/).

Also I deployed and successfully used some apps.

But when I try to deploy a major project using the X-all.wlapp, the upload fails with the message:

> Connection failure. Check server log for details.

When I upload single files I am able to to deploy the common one (6.6mb in my case), but not the android one (13mb here).
Then I checked -in several attempts- the elapsed time and I see that exactly after 60seconds the connection is broken.

May I customize some server parameter in the MFPF template image? Other solutions?

As per suggestion, here the related event in log files:

> [3/17/16 20:29:03:049 UTC] 00000124
>   com.worklight.core.ilmt.WorklightILMTLogger                  I
>   FWLSE0277I: Creating an ILMT record in the file
>   '/var/ibm/common/slm/0fc91957c76d998ca26d77e18fd3d7e5.slmtag'.
>
> [3/17/16 20:29:57:226 UTC] 00000103
>   com.ibm.worklight.management.ui.servlet.ServiceProxy         E
>   Throwable Connection closed: Read failed.  Possible end of stream
>   encountered.  while redirecting request to
>   [http://172.31.XX.YY:9080/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/*my-mfpf-runtime*/applications?async=true](http://172.31.XX.YY:9080/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/_my-mfpf-runtime_/applications?async=true)

Comment: Can you provide your server logs? 
To get this you will need the to login to your container using cf command line utility. In case you do not have the cf cli utility
- Install cf utility https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ov.html#container_cli_ov
- Execute cf ic ps  (this will list all the running containers)
- Execute cf ic exec <id of the container under question> 
The logs can be located within the container under /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/logs

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I keep updated this thread.

Comment: You can work around the problem, by deploying the wlapp files specific to different environments. Say, instead of deploying a single MyApp_all.wlapp, you can try deploying individual environment specific wlapp files one by one... MyApp_common.wlapp, MyApp_iPhone.wlapp, etc

With which we reduced the size of the single big chunk upload.

Comment: @Wakkko This is a defect and a fix for this is in progress.

Comment: thank you all for the quick support, looking forward for the fix.

Comment: Should be available now.

Comment: thanks I checked the solution that reports (for the readers) "Timeouts were increased, especially for uploads of adapter and wlapp.
worklightconsole.war must be redeployed on the application server".
So it mean that something has been reconfigured underline and it needs a redeploy OR we need an updated console war to substitute the original one in the template?

Answer (score 1):

Update: the iFix has been uploaded and hsould be available from IBM Fix Central.

There is an open APAR for this issue: PI59605 MFPF ON IBM BLUEMIX CONTAINER - WLAPP UPLOAD FAILS AFTER 60SECONDS

If you want to be notified once the fix is ready, you need to open an IBM PMR (support ticket). Otherwise, the fix will eventually be found on IBM Fix Central.